# How can I inspire my group to start using an online collaborative tool more?

Tags: project-management, collaboration

I'm in a project with 4 other people, and I've been willing to fully adopt a collaborative tool in order to make it possible to share information and store data (PDFs, DOCs, etc.) in an online tool, rather than doing it by e-mail. The problem is that I'm the only one enforcing it; actually I'm the only one using it. The others only use it when I ask them to do so.

How would you handle this? Have you experienced something similar, if so, what have you done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep plugging at it.

When asked where some documentation is, point them to the online resource. When emailing around, use links.

When writing new documentation put it directly online and point to it and only to it. Encourage the same behavior from others.

If something isn't online, ask why.

When it is time to update the documentation, tell your colleagues that it has been updated - perhaps point out that since it is online, they do not need to change their local copy (if they had one).

Help them discover the benefits, or they will never buy in to this way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

To what extent have you shown them how to use the tool?  Have you asked them if they have any difficulties using it?  You need to find out why they don't like to use it and try to remedy that.  Note that this is exploratory and there is the question of how well do those other 4 trust you as these may be rather personal answers they may give and thus some sensitivity may be required.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was already mentioned, try to show them why to use the tool by coming up with scenarios of the value of this tool. You can buy the team lunch and present your idea, some may be ready to listen for a free pizza :)